# Want to filter the json data into node.js using some kind of loop

Tags: node.js

I used this as reference but this only shows the first value found but i want all the possible values to be printed.

```
var inventory = [{ name: 'apples', quantity: 2 }, { name: 'bananas', quantity: 0 }, { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }, { name: 'cherries', quantity: 8 }];

function findCherries(fruit) { return fruit.name === 'cherries'; }

console.log(inventory.filter(findCherries));
```

Comment: I created a fiddle to check your code it showing all the matched objects in the console. please check https://jsfiddle.net/2ccLkqe9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the filter function is supposed to return you an array, so I'm guessing your problem is simply that the console.log function doesn't display all of it. Try `console.log(inventory.filter(findCherries).toString())`